# clip.isRunning() not working

Tags: java, multithreading, audio, javasound

I am trying to make the background music for a game. For some reason, after the song is played for the first time it won't play again. What am I doing wrong and how can i fix it? I know i can use .loop() but i want it to repeat forever, and .loop() will eventually stop.

```
 public class playSong 
    extends Thread
 {

    Clip clip=null;

    playSong()
    {
        start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            if(clip==null)
            {
                playSound("fax.wav");
            }
            else if(!clip.isRunning())
            {playSound("fax.wav");}
        }
    }

    public void playSound(String name)
    {
    try {
            File file=new File(this.getClass().getResource(name).getFile());
            AudioInputStream audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audio);
            clip.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best would be to use the looping option already existing in **Clip**.

```
clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
```

Here is already an answer describing that : [Audio clip looping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8980146/354831).  It is supposed to fix your endling loop problem that you describe by keeping the thread running.

**UPDATE :**

Here is a full working example made of your code, modified.

```
public class PlaySong extends Thread
{
    Clip clip=null;

    public PlaySong()
    {
        start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        playSound("fax.wav");

        for(;;)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
    }

    public void playSound(String name)
    {
        try
        {
            File file = new File(this.getClass().getResource(name).getFile());
            AudioInputStream audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audio);
            clip.start();
            clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.print(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```